# Symfony: Loading fixtures of objects with multiple column primary key which are also foreign keys

Tags: mysql, symfony1, schema, foreign-keys, fixtures

im writing fixtures for my project in symfony, and i have preblems when trying to add fixtures to objects with a multiple column primary key, which is also foreign key to other table.

Here's the schema in MySql Workbench:

[image: MySQL WorkBench representation of the schema]

I generated the sql code with workbench, and then generated the `schema.yml` file with the symfony task `php symfony doctrine:build-schema`.

this is the sql generated for these tables:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`MetodoEnvio`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`MetodoEnvio` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`MetodoEnvio` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`ZonaEnvio`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`ZonaEnvio` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`ZonaEnvio` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `numero` INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `etiqueta` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `numero`) ,
  INDEX `fk_ZonaEnvio_MetodoEnvio` (`id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `numeroZona_INDEX` (`numero` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ZonaEnvio_MetodoEnvio`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`MetodoEnvio` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PrecioEnvio`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`PrecioEnvio` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PrecioEnvio` (
  `idMetodo` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `zona` INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `inicioRango` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Marca el inicio del rango de peso para el cual este precio aplica.' ,
  `finRango` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL COMMENT 'Marca el fin del rango de peso para el cual este precio aplica.' ,
  `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMetodo`, `inicioRango`, `finRango`, `zona`) ,
  INDEX `fk_PrecioEnvio_ZonaEnvio` (`idMetodo` ASC, `zona` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PrecioEnvio_ZonaEnvio`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMetodo` , `zona` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`ZonaEnvio` (`id` , `numero` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`IntervaloMetodoEnvio`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`IntervaloMetodoEnvio` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`IntervaloMetodoEnvio` (
  `idMetodo` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `zona` INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `intervalo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL ,
  `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMetodo`, `zona`) ,
  INDEX `fk_IntervaloMetodoEnvio_ZonaEnvio` (`idMetodo` ASC, `zona` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_IntervaloMetodoEnvio_ZonaEnvio`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idMetodo` , `zona` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`ZonaEnvio` (`id` , `numero` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

this is the schema generated for these tables:

```
MetodoEnvio:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: MetodoEnvio
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nombre:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    precio:
      type: 'decimal(10, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    TiendaOrden:
      local: id
      foreign: metodoenvio
      type: many
    ZonaEnvio:
      local: id
      foreign: id
      type: many
ZonaEnvio:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ZonaEnvio
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    numero:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    etiqueta:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    MetodoEnvio:
      local: id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    IntervaloMetodoEnvio:
      local: id
      foreign: idmetodo
      type: many
    IntervaloMetodoEnvio_2:
      class: IntervaloMetodoEnvio
      local: numero
      foreign: zona
      type: many
    PrecioEnvio:
      local: id
      foreign: idmetodo
      type: many
    PrecioEnvio_2:
      class: PrecioEnvio
      local: numero
      foreign: zona
      type: many
PrecioEnvio:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: PrecioEnvio
  columns:
    idmetodo:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    zona:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    iniciorango:
      type: 'decimal(10, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    finrango:
      type: 'decimal(10, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    precio:
      type: 'decimal(10, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    ZonaEnvio:
      local: idmetodo
      foreign: id
      type: one
    ZonaEnvio_2:
      class: ZonaEnvio
      local: zona
      foreign: numero
      type: one
IntervaloMetodoEnvio:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: IntervaloMetodoEnvio
  columns:
    idmetodo:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    zona:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    intervalo:
      type: 'decimal(10, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    precio:
      type: 'decimal(10, 2)'
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    ZonaEnvio:
      local: idmetodo
      foreign: id
      type: one
    ZonaEnvio_2:
      class: ZonaEnvio
      local: zona
      foreign: numero
      type: one
```

Then, i wrote the following fixtures:

```
MetodoEnvio:
  personal:
    nombre: Retiro Personal
    precio: 0.0

  mrw:
    nombre: MRW
    precio: 5.0

  dhl:
    nombre: DHL
    precio: -1.0
ZonaEnvio:
  dhl_zona1:
    MetodoEnvio: dhl
    numero: 1
    etiqueta: DHL (Envios en la Zona Metropolitana)

  dhl_zona5:
    MetodoEnvio: dhl
    numero: 5
    etiqueta: DHL (Envios al interior del pais)
PrecioEnvio:
  fila1_zona1:
    ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona1
    inicioRango: 0.00
    finRango: 0.50
    precio: 26.90

  fila1_zona5:
    ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona5
    inicioRango: 00
    finRango: 0.50
    precio: 59.60
IntervaloMetodoEnvio:
  dhl_zona_1:
    ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona1
    intervalo: 0.5
    precio: 3.05

  dhl_zona_5:
    ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona5
    intervalo: 0.5
    precio: 7.15
```

When i do the command `php symfony doctrine:data-load`, it returns the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`PrecioEnvio`, CONSTRAINT `fk_PrecioEnvio_ZonaEnvio` FOREIGN KEY (`idMetodo`, `zona`) REFERENCES `ZonaEnvio` (`id`, `numero`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Since the error has to do with foreign keys, i think it might have something to do with my references in the schema, in lines like `ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona1`. How do i reference the "parent object"? I think this is not like an inheritance but instead like a weak relationship...

Please forgive the length of my question, but i wanted to provide you with all the necessary information so you can help me!

THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a mysql constraint error which means the value being inserted does not exist in the related table.

Your fixture format does not match my understanding of what it should be for the version 1.x symfony/doctrine combination.  Take a look at this help for the proper format:  http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/05-Data-Fixtures.  For example, creating a row with id 1:

```
MetodoEnvio:
  MetodoEnvio_1:
    nombre: Retiro Personal
    precio: 0.0
```

Then when you need to refer to a table that relates to MetodoEnvio with id = 1, you can utilize MetodoEnvio_1, although you probably can simply use id: 1, knowing that the id will be 1.

Comment: Thanks, but what you call `MetodoEnvio_1` does not need to be called like that. This is just a name so i can refer to it later in my fixtures. In fact, `MetodoEnvio`  and `ZonaEnvio` are the only tables loaded correctly by my fixtures when the task is executed. The problem is when adding `IntervaloMetodoEnvio` or `PrecioEnvio` whose primary keys are also foreign keys to `ZonaEnvio` and have two fields. That's what im asking here... anyway, thanks for taking the time of reading! if you have another idea, please, don't hesitate posting it! I have not solved this issue yet...

Comment: When you use the Table_1, the key will be 1, so it's predictable. It seems that the keys of the parent table are not being plugged into the dependent table in the way you assume.

Comment: Thanks again, but nope, the number `_1` after the name of the instance in the fixture does not forces it to be the first. At least not with doctrine. Doctrine arranges fixtures to be loaded in the right order. And even if that would be correct, it is not what im asking. My issue is with the tables mentioned in the previous comment, which reference `MetodoEnvio`. Besides, we don't use keys explicitly in fixtures. We use references to the object. This reasoning led me to the answer.

Comment: It has to do with the relations generated in the schema. I'll post my answer when the mandatory 8 hours pass, since i have less than 100 reputation. Even though, If anyone posts a right answer before the mandatory time is elapsed, i'll accept that answer. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Throoze:  I did understand the problem, although I guess I didn't do the best job explaining it.  My point was that you were assuming that because a table had a multi-column key, that naming it as a fixture would then allow you to reference it later, and have it bring all its keys along to fill a child row with a foreign key relationship.  That didn't seem to work in your model, so I was simply trying to suggest some other ways of forcing the fixture loader to get around the problem.  It's great to hear that you did find a way around this, and will update with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was. It has to do with how the relations were defined in the `schema.yml` file. Notice it represents the two fields primary key defining two relations to the same class:

```
.
.
.
  relations:
     ZonaEnvio:
        local: idmetodo
        foreign: id
        type: one
     ZonaEnvio_2:
        class: ZonaEnvio
        local: zona
        foreign: numero
        type: one
```

Relatios are defined like this in `PrecioEnvio` and `IntervaloMetodoEnvio`, both weak entities of `ZonaEnvio`. So, I just needed to give values for both relations in my fixtures, and point them to the same instance of the `ZonaEnvio` object previously defined. Like this:

```
IntervaloMetodoEnvio:
  dhl_zona_1:
    ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona1
    ZonaEnvio_2: dhl_zona1
    intervalo: 0.5
    precio: 3.05

  dhl_zona_5:
    ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona5
    ZonaEnvio_2: dhl_zona5
    intervalo: 0.5
    precio: 7.15

PrecioEnvio:
  fila1_zona1:
    ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona1
    ZonaEnvio_2: dhl_zona1
    inicioRango: 0.00
    finRango: 0.50
    precio: 26.90

  fila1_zona5:
    ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona5
    ZonaEnvio_2: dhl_zona5
    inicioRango: 00
    finRango: 0.50
    precio: 59.60
```

Notice

```
ZonaEnvio: dhl_zona1
ZonaEnvio_2: dhl_zona1
```

both lines are in the same fixture definition and point to the same instance. That way, fixtures are successfully loaded.

Thanks anyways for your efforts gview!